# Si la respuesta del input es diferente a varias palabras entonces devolver algo diferente

Tags: python, input, print

```
canciones = {
    "cancion1": "letra de una cancion 1"
}
cancionesdos = {
    "cancion2": "letra de una cancion 2"
}
cancionestres = {
    "cancion3": "letra de una cancion 3"
}
cancionescuatro = {
    "cancion4": "letra de una cancion 4"
}
cancionElejida = input("inserte cancion mi eztimado inzano >>")

if cancionElejida == "cancion1":
    print(canciones["cancion1"])

if cancionElejida == "cancion2":
    print(cancionesdos["cancion2"])

if cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionestres["cancion3"])

if cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionescuatro["cancion3"])
```

Aca abajo quiero poner que si la respuesta de la persona no es (cancion1, cancion2 y las otras) entonces aparesca un mensaje que dice "no se" ya se que el mensaje se pone "print("no se") pero no se como hacer la otra parte del codigo diganme pls

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que quieres lo único que necesitas es añadir un `else` al final de las condiciones, también te recomiendo que cambies los `if` después del primero por `elif` ya que aunque el resultado sea el mismo, es una buena práctica usar `elif` lo que haces con esto es encadenar las condicionales y si de tus condiciones se cumple, el resto no se comprueban.

Lo que hace el `else` del final es que si no se cumple ninguna de las condiciones anteriores imprime el lo que hay dentro del `else`.

Te dejo el código corregido a continuación :

```
canciones = {
    "cancion1": "letra de una cancion 1"
}
cancionesdos = {
    "cancion2": "letra de una cancion 2"
}
cancionestres = {
    "cancion3": "letra de una cancion 3"
}
cancionescuatro = {
    "cancion4": "letra de una cancion 4"
}
cancionElejida = input("inserte cancion mi eztimado inzano >>")

if cancionElejida == "cancion1":
    print(canciones["cancion1"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion2":
    print(cancionesdos["cancion2"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionestres["cancion3"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionescuatro["cancion3"])

else:
     print("La canción introducida no esta en la lista de canciones")
```

Comment: No creo que un simple "else" sea el mayor asunto con su código. Su manejo de los diccionarios, y su unión con el if es super cuestionable. Creo que se tiene que comentar eso en la respuesta. Mira abajo la respuesta de @CandidMoe

Comment: Cierto, la respuesta de @CandiMoe es la correcta, se me habían pasado por completo los diccionarios. Gracias por comentar

Answer (score 1):

Eso no se hace. Si tienes múltiples instancias de algo las pones en un contenedor (lista, diccionario, ...)

```
canciones = {
    "cancion1": "letra de una cancion 1",
    "cancion2": "letra de una cancion 2",
    "cancion3": "letra de una cancion 3",
    "cancion4": "letra de una cancion 4",
}

cancionElejida = input("inserte cancion mi eztimado inzano >>")
if cancionElejida in canciones:
    print(canciones[cancionElejida])
else:
    print("no sé")
```

Este código hace lo mismo, pero más corto.

Comment: Creo que esta es la mejor respuesta. Las demás dejan pasar por alto esa cosa malísima de sus diccionarios. Muy malas respuestas por dejar pasar eso. Sin embargo, esta respuesta no tiene lo de la respuesta de "no sé" en caso de no encontrar ninguna.

Comment: @Cuauhtli. Cierto. Corregido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `elif` en lugar de `if`. Básicamente lo que hace es si el prime `if` es falso checa los siguientes `elif`, si entra al primer `if` o a alguno de los siguientes `elif` ya no revisa los otros. Después dejas un valor default con `else` si es que no entro al `if` o a algún `elif` entonces entra al `else`

```
canciones = {
    "cancion1": "letra de una cancion 1"
}
cancionesdos = {
    "cancion2": "letra de una cancion 2"
}
cancionestres = {
    "cancion3": "letra de una cancion 3"
}
cancionescuatro = {
    "cancion4": "letra de una cancion 4"
}
cancionElejida = input("inserte cancion mi eztimado inzano >>")

if cancionElejida == "cancion1":
    print(canciones["cancion1"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion2":
    print(cancionesdos["cancion2"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionestres["cancion3"])

elif cancionElejida == "cancion3":
    print(cancionescuatro["cancion3"])
else:
    print("no sé")
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron en otras respuestas, tu mayor problema no es la falta de un `else`, sino que estás usando mal los diccionarios.

En mi propuesta de respuesta crearé un diccionario con las canciones y las letras, y las pediré con el método `get` **que me dará por default** (osea, en caso de no encontrar la canción solicitada) **el mensaje de error que pediste**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

UNKNOWN_SONG_MESSAGE = "No se"
PROMPT_MESSAGE = "inserte cancion mi eztimado inzano >> "

canciones_y_letras = {
    "cancion1": "letra de una cancion 1",
    "cancion2": "letra de una cancion 2",
    "cancion3": "letra de una cancion 3",
    "cancion4": "letra de una cancion 4"
}

eleccion = input(PROMPT_MESSAGE)
letra_cancion_elegida = canciones_y_letras.get(eleccion, UNKNOWN_SONG_MESSAGE)

print(letra_cancion_elegida)
```

Nota como el código se hace mucho más resumido y legible.

La magia aquí lo hace el método `get(<clave>, <valor por defecto>)` que tienen los diccionarios, el cual no sólo trae el valor del diccionario cuya clave coincida, sino que, **en caso de no tener clave que coincida**, te regresa el valor por defecto. Ahí es donde devolvemos el valor "No se" que pediste.

### Opcion 2, short-if

Otra opción que no es de mi agrado, pero funciona, es con un short-if:

```py
letra_cancion_elegida = "No se" \
    if eleccion not in canciones_y_letras \
    else canciones_y_letras[eleccion]

print(letra_cancion_elegida)
```

### Nota

Repetir tu uso del *if-elif-else* como lo ponen algunas respuestas aquí, es muy mala idea. Deja al código dificil de seguir, además que no aprovecha las potencialidades de python y su paradigma orientado a objetos.

El if-else aquí, además de usar un diccionario para cada par valor-clave, tiene una gran cantidad de [code smells](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hediondez_del_c%C3%B3digo) que si bien no alteran la funcionalidad de tu código, lo hace ilegible, inmantenible, no escalable, y aumenta el riesgo de errores a futuro, además que te quitará a tí, a tus compañeros, amigos, y profesores o clientes precioso tiempo y energía cada que se revise tu código en el futuro.

Recuerda que lo que programes hoy, lo vas a tener que revisar en una semana o mes cuando hayas olvidado el hilo de lo que habías hecho.